# Reset DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE value

Tags: django

I for some stupid reason changed my DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and now none of my manage.py commands work. I did this on my OSX machine

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = myproj.settings
```

Can I reset it so that it will work again. I guess I'm not quite sure how this happened. This is the error I get

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'project.path.settings' (Is it on sys.path?):
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you just need to do:

`export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = django.conf.global_settings`

[Here are the settings docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/).

Also, the export function will only keep those settings alive for your current shell session, if you didn't set =, or edit any configurations, you should be able to terminate your session and start anew.

Comment: I ran it inside the terminal window, not a shell session. I closed out the terminal, even restarted the computer and the variable is still set to the incorrect value I gave it

Comment: Terminal == Shell. But hey, I think it only uses something other than the default settings if the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is set. So try doing:

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=

If it is set to nothing, it should revert to the defaults.

You can see what it is currently set to at any time by doing:

echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Comment: I'm stupid and also had the variable assignment in my settings.py file. Once I took it out it was fine. Sorry for hassel and thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

One thing which can be done is to close the current terminal and start it again. I did the same mistake of changing the variable but I found this alternative solution. Hope this works for you.